# Page refresh required to see node_save changes written in hook_node_view?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

Trying to assign a target id to EntityField (field_family_log) on a node (study node-parent node) in hook_node_view(). I have added some conditions to check and assigned target_id to the node. However, to see the assigned target node, requires refreshing the page!

target node is assigned during the first page load, but to see the changes on the browser, requires page refresh/load.

Current code:

```
function study_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {

  if ($node->type == 'study') {

    if(!isset($node->field_family_log)) {
      $log_nid = get_family_log_if_exists($node->nid);
      if (is_numeric($log_nid)) {
          $node->field_family_log['und'][0]['target_id'] = $log_nid;
          node_save($node);
          drupal_set_message("Log assigned");
          //return $node;      //..... this line also did not help! ......
      }
      else {
          drupal_set_message('No Log created for the family');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should not be doing this (updating/saving operations) in hook_node_view. You also don't need to return the object. The only thing you should be doing here is appending information to the object.

Comment: Should be `if ($node->type == 'study') {` with double **`==`**

Comment: @Kevin , thanks for the suggestion. Where else you think I can do this part? I want to check if a family log exists for a Study node and if exists want to assign it as target_id to Study node. I am doing this in hook_node_view because family log is added any time before or after adding study node.

Comment: @Maddy you should use [hook_node_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7.x) which is triggered when a node is being inserted or updated.